# Help on Regular Expressions

Tags: asp.net, html, regex, replace

I have over 2000 aspx documents that all hold the same heading that I need to remove:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<HTML lang="en">
<HEAD>

<TITLE>External Reference Investopedia</TITLE>
<META NAME="author" CONTENT="DERCHEC">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<A NAME="topofpagebibliographyitem2aspx"></A>
```

Both the `<TITLE>` and `<A>` tag change in every file.

I need some help creating a regular expression that will select all the above text for me. I am currently using TextCrawler to work through these document in a batch. If better tools and methods are out there. Please let me know.

Regards,

CD

Comment: If they are all the same, can't you just simply remove the top 9 lines or so?

Answer (score 1):

Use visual studio find and replace in files. In your find options choose that you want to use regular expressions (its a checkbox)

Find:

```
{\<Title>{.*}\</title\>}
```

Replace with nothing - IE leave it blank.
This should get you started : )

Option 2 - download ultraedit and do a find and replace in files on the text block - done : )

Comment: `{.*}` - sure? Is there no reluctant quantifier in VS search-and-replace?

Comment: For this regex one has to be careful to not check "Match case" in the VS search dialog's find options. (TITLE != Title != title)

Comment: @Tomalak right, this could be a problem replacing the `<A>`s. Should change to ...`{.*?}`. Don't know if that works as expected in VS.

Comment: not sure - I use regexs maybe twice a year - so Im certain there is a better way : )  I know ultraedit will allow you to find the whole block of text and replace in files - thats probably the easiest just download the demo

Answer (score 0):

Simple!  The regular expression will be exactly the same text you need to remove.  So if you want to match:

```
<HTML lang="en">
```

your regular expression will be:

```
<HTML lang="en">
```

The only time you'll have a problem is when you have a character which has a reserved meaning, in that instance you just need to prefix with a \ .

So if you need to match a question mark (?) the regex would be \?

Comment: Why use a regular expression, then? ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the bit you want to remove always ends with the `</A>` tag. The you could just use a normal string split function in any language.